# how to print the content of pages inside the front end area

Tags: pages, the-content

i'm new to wordpress and i'm trying to create a website. i need display the content of the pages when corresponding menu items are clicked. my page.php contain

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                      $page_data= $post->ID;
                      if($page_data=='116')
                      {
                      ?>    

                      <center><b><h2>WELCOME TO THE CLINIC!!</h2></b></center>
                     <?php 

                      }
                     else{

                     ?>

                      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                      <?php
                    the_content();

                     }
                      endwhile; ?>
```

but my content is not displaying. title is showing properly. what is the mistake in the code? please help me.

Comment: I don't see a mistake in the code, and it works when I test it (though your markup uses a deprecated/unsupported tag).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that either (1) `the-content()` is being filtered to show nothing or (2) that the content is being sent to the web page, but something is hiding it.

First, make sure there is content to display:

```
} else {
?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php
    echo 'Before Content';
    echo $post->post_content;
    echo 'After Content';
}
```

If nothing is hiding the content (like JavaScript or CSS), it should should show up on the page between *Before Content* and *After Content*. If not, double check by looking at the browser page source to see if anything was added at that point.

If it shows up, replace `echo $post->post_content;` with `the_content()` and reload the page. If the content is being filtered it is probably on the `the_content` filter. Try removing those filter functions:

```
} else {
?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php
    remove_all_filters( 'the_content' );
    echo 'Before Content';
    the_content();
    echo 'After Content';
}
```

Does the content show up now? If it does, there is a filter in the theme or plugin files which is removing the content before it is displayed.

In practice, you would want to find that code and disable it (probably) by removing that faulty filter function. `remove_all_filters()` is a the drastic option. It can remove filters you want on there. Like filters that add Social Media buttons or helpful links.

Comment: but frnd it is entering into the else part thats why it prints the title properly. but the content i wrote from admin side is not showing.

Comment: Sorry. Then something may be filtering the content before it displays. You could try removing those first. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, however I think the main failure is to call a page #116, if this page not exist on your WP site the front area or HOME page will not display any data. Normaly to avoid page ID # I use the code  `if (is_page('name-of-page'))  {?>`  
 Some times is better than PAGE ID because the ID number not allways is the same on new WP install, just remember to set your permalinks to pretty using  `/%permalinks%/`

Comment: but sir it is displaying the title correctly. do u have any idea why it is not showing the content?

Comment: @user007 try to close each php line and add a div for content:  <h1 class="entry-title">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</h1>
<div class="content"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div>

Comment: i already wrote the above whole php code in <div class="content"> sir. i forgot to mention that in here.

Answer (score 0):

i did it using $post->post_content; that is directly getting and displaying data from database. this works perfect for me.